# How to add new data to a table with a many-to-many relationship with a bidirectional relationship. TypeORM

Tags: typeorm, nest, nestjs-typeorm

I work with "Nest.js" and "TypeORM"

I have two entities, "User" and "Usergroups", I am trying to add a user to one of the groups. But for some reason it doesn't work.
What you need to do to make it work ?

---

**user.entity.ts**

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @BeforeInsert()
  async hashPassword() {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.pass, 10);
    this.pass = hash;
  }

  @BeforeInsert()
  async createConfirmId() {
    this.confirm_id = uuid.v4();
  }

  @BeforeInsert()
  async addCustomGroup() {

  }

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column({ default: 'user name' })
  name: string;

  @Column()
  pass: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  auth_status: boolean;

  @Column({ default: false })
  confirmation: boolean;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  confirm_id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  accessToken: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  refreshToken: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Order, (order) => order.user)
  orders: Order[];

  @ManyToMany(() => Usergroup, (usergroup) => usergroup.users)
  @JoinTable()
  usergroups: Usergroup[];
}
```

**usergroup.entity.ts**

```
@Entity()
export class Usergroup {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.usergroups, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  users: User[];
}
```

This is a business logic code that doesn't work.

**user.service.ts**

```
      const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne({
        where: {
          id: user_id,
        },
      });

      const userGroup = await this.usergroupRepository.findOne({
        where: {
          id: group_id,
        },
      });

      if (user && userGroup) {
        user.usergroups.push(userGroup);
        userGroup.users.push(user);

        await this.usersRepository.save(user);
        await this.usergroupRepository.save(userGroup);
      }
```

I expected that it would add data, but this does not happen, errors also do not occur.

Comment: Have you debug your code? Do both user & userGroup were actually found? Try to console.log them and see what's going on. Also, I noticed that you do not join relations when you use `.findOne` method. This means that if the statemnt `if (user && userGroup)` is true then u will receive an error like "unable to read .push() of undefined in user.usergroups" or something like that. The same things are for `userGroup.users`

Comment: Also, if you want to add relation entities this way `user.usergroups.push(userGroup)` for users and usergroup, as far as I know you should set `cascade: true` option in both places (in User and UserGroup entities).